# How to make the NDPA of this question?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Say $w^R $ is the reverse of $w$.

E.g.: $\epsilon^R = \epsilon$ and $(abbab)^R = babba$

Now say $L = \{ww^R | w \in L (a^*b^*)\}$

Draw the NDPA $M$ with $L(M) = M$

I understand NDPA's, however I don't understand how to derive this NDPA from the given information.

note: this is not homework, rather an exam-prep question.

Comment: Still, what have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: @Qwerty reviewed the lectures, homework material and check the exam explanation, but I can't make any sense of it...